# elmah with customErrors not emailing unless it's a 404

Tags: asp.net-mvc, exception, elmah

I am playing around with Elmah to see if I want to use that as my error handling solution.  I installed it, hard coded an exception into my page, hit the page wholla!  Got my email, everything is happy.  However, when I added the customError node to my web.config to redirect to a friendly error page, the email was not sent but I was redirected to my friendly error page.

Strangely, when I browsed to a page that doesn't exist on my site, I was redirected to home (as I set in my customErrors) but I DID receive the email...that could be problematic as I don't want to get a billion emails when people hit my site and add "whatever.php" to the end of the url.

So I have two questions: 1) why would the exception that is being thrown NOT send me an email and 2) how can I tell Elmah NOT to send me emails for 404s?

Comment: As an aside - redirecting users to the home page for missing URLs is an anti-pattern and should be avoided. All it is likely to do is confuse users - "why did I go to the home page when I clicked on x link". Instead have a dedicated 404 page which simply and clearly explains the problem, and ideally helps users find the page that they were looking for (with a site map for example). I'd also suggest periodically reviewing your logged 404 errors (or web master tools) to check if you have any broken links etc. in order to help avoid the errors in the first place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can filter things with elmah like such in your Global.asax.cs:

```
    //ELMAH Filtering
    protected void ErrorLog_Filtering(object sender, ExceptionFilterEventArgs e)
    {
        FilterError404(e);
    }

    protected void ErrorMail_Filtering(object sender, ExceptionFilterEventArgs e)
    {
        FilterError404(e);
    }

    //Dimiss 404 errors for ELMAH
    private void FilterError404(ExceptionFilterEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Exception.GetBaseException() is HttpException)
        {
            HttpException ex = (HttpException)e.Exception.GetBaseException();

            if (ex.GetHttpCode() == 404)
            {
                e.Dismiss();
            }
        }
    }
```

So add the call to FilterError404 to any part of the filtering.  The above example will have it filter 404 for both ErrorLog and Email.  Also check out:
http://code.google.com/p/elmah/wiki/ErrorFiltering

You can also do Filtering By Source as described in the link:

```
<elmah>
    ...
    <errorFilter>
        <test>
            <and>
                <equal binding="HttpStatusCode" value="404" type="Int32" />
                <regex binding="FilterSourceType.Name" pattern="mail" />
            </and>
        </test>
    </errorFilter>
</elmah>
```

Check web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- 
    Note: As an alternative to hand editing this file you can use the 
    web admin tool to configure settings for your application. Use
    the Website->Asp.Net Configuration option in Visual Studio.
    A full list of settings and comments can be found in 
    machine.config.comments usually located in 
    \Windows\Microsoft.Net\Framework\v2.x\Config 
-->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="elmah">
      <section name="security" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.SecuritySectionHandler, Elmah" />
      <section name="errorLog" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorLogSectionHandler, Elmah" />
      <section name="errorMail" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorMailSectionHandler, Elmah" />
      <section name="errorFilter" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterSectionHandler, Elmah" />
    </sectionGroup>   
  </configSections>
  <appSettings />
  <!-- ELMAH: Configuration -->
  <elmah>
    <security allowRemoteAccess="1" />
    <errorLog type="Elmah.SqlErrorLog, Elmah" connectionStringName="Elmah.Sql" />
    <errorMail defaultCredentials="true" from="someuser@example.com" to="someuser@example.com, someuser2@example.com" subject="Error (STAGING): {0}" async="true" smtpPort="25" smtpServer="192.168.1.1" userName="smtpUserName" password="smtpPassword" />
  </elmah>
  <connectionStrings>  
    <add name="Elmah.Sql" connectionString="Data Source=192.168.1.1;database=DBName;integrated security=false;User ID=MyUserName;Password=MyPassword" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp deliveryMethod="Network" from="someuser@example.com">
        <network defaultCredentials="true" host="192.168.1.1" port="25" userName="smtpUserName" password="smtpPassword" />
      </smtp>
      <!-- Use this setting for development
      <smtp deliveryMethod="SpecifiedPickupDirectory">
        <specifiedPickupDirectory pickupDirectoryLocation="C:\Temp" />
      </smtp>
      -->
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>
  <system.web>
    <!-- 
            Set compilation debug="true" to insert debugging 
            symbols into the compiled page. Because this 
            affects performance, set this value to true only 
            during development.
    -->
    <compilation debug="true">
      <assemblies>
        ...........................
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>

        .......................
    <!--
            The <customErrors> section enables configuration 
            of what to do if/when an unhandled error occurs 
            during the execution of a request. Specifically, 
            it enables developers to configure html error pages 
            to be displayed in place of a error stack trace.
      -->
    <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="~/Home/MyErrorPage" />
  .............................
    <httpHandlers>
        ..............................
      <!--ELMAH-->
      <add verb="POST,GET,HEAD" path="/MyErrorPage/elmah.axd" type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah" />
    </httpHandlers>
    <httpModules>
  ........................
      <!-- ELMAH: Logging module -->
      <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah" />
      <add name="ErrorMail" type="Elmah.ErrorMailModule, Elmah" />
    </httpModules>
  </system.web>

  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
    .............................
    <!-- ELMAH-->
      <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah" />
      <add name="ErrorMail" type="Elmah.ErrorMailModule, Elmah" />
      <add name="ErrorFilter" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterModule, Elmah" />
    </modules>
    <handlers>
    ..............
      <!--ELMAH-->
      <add name="Elmah" verb="POST,GET,HEAD" path="/MyErrorPage/elmah.axd" type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
 ..................
</configuration>
```

FYI: NuGET Package also available as explained by Scott Hanselman:
http://www.hanselman.com/blog/NuGetPackageOfTheWeek7ELMAHErrorLoggingModulesAndHandlersWithSQLServerCompact.aspx

Comment: great thanks!  that helped a lot.  any idea why my exceptions aren't triggering emails though?

Comment: Ok compare your web.config with mine see if there are any differences.

Comment: used your web.config (added in the missing pieces), still not working.  I talked to a buddy of mine at work and he helped me get it going.  I had to add some custom classes and then call them from global.asax to make it happen.  Really appreciate your help.

Comment: That's great I also had some trouble at first implementing it but after 30 odd pages (more like 5) I got it going.  FYI: is a NuGet package as well as explained above.  Is there something I left off that needed to be done when others look at this post?